# How to get item from previous list in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists and another list like this:

```
new_list = []

lst_of_lst = [['MHK', 549, 'ABC', 3], ['OMK', 567, 'TTT', 8], ['KDH', 675, 'TGH' , 12]]
lst = ['MHK', 553, 'ABC']
```

I have to observe when `lst_of_lst[1]` is grater than `lst[1]` and then "go back" to the previous list to get `lst_of_lst[3]`, in this case "3", because 553 (from lst) is between 549 and 567. 3 should afterwards be appended to `new_list`, but this is not a problem.

I have tried with:

```
if lst_of_lst[1] > lst[1]:
    new_list.append(lst_of_lst[3][:-1])
```

But this does not work. To be more specific: How should the append look like to get the number from the last list in lst_of_lst that is not grater than list[1].
Hope you understand my question.

Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question with the codes that you've tried already and tell us what's the exact problem, so that we can understand the problem better and help you accordingly.

Comment: I have tried to be more specific about my question. I am very new to this. Thank you for letting me know and I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: What should the behavior be if the key is less than the first of the sorted values?

Comment: `lst_of_lst[3]` this doesn't make sense, you only have three elements. Plus, what is exactly your understanding of a list being greater than an element of a list?

Comment: @DavisHerring Then it should just pass.

Comment: @formi23 I have four elements in `lst_of_lst`. What I mean is I have to see when the `element[1] of lst_of_lst` is greater than the `element[1] of lst`. When `element[1] of lst_of_lst` is found to be greater, then I have to "go back" to the previous list (in this case `['MHK', 549, 'ABC', 3]`) and append the number `3`to the `new_list`.

Comment: You’re confusing `lst_of_lst` with one of its elements throughout.  Try rewording your question: you might discover the answer yourself.

Comment: Cheers @User for the explanation. But as commented above - you don't have 4 elements in your `lst_of_lst` - it has only 3 element, and each one of those is a list itself(with 4 elements). So if you want to compare element of `lst_of_lst` that is equal to 567 and an element of `lst` that is equal to 553 then you'll have to reach them as `lst_of_lst[1][1]` and `lst[1]`. If you only go like `lst_of_lst[1]` then you're comparing the list `['OMK', 567, 'TTT', 8]` to a number 553

Answer (score 0):

To point out what's wrong with your solution -

- `lst_of_lst[1] > lst[1]` - here you compare a list to a value, which will give you a TypeError.
- You're trying to append an element that doesn't exist - `lst_of_lst[3][:-1]` - `lst_of_lst[3]` is out of range, the index only goes 0,1,2. Finally, [:-1] sets a range of elements up to the last one, not the last value.

Your question is very obscure since it is not clear what you want to do exactly to be able to generalise the solution, i.e. go iteratively over all elements) - otherwise you can just do this manually. 
To specifically answer your question you should try this

`new_lst = []
 if lst_of_lst[1][1] > lst[1]:
     new_lst.append(lst_of_lst[0][-1])`